# How grab the System.out from remote debugging java app?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm able to remotely debug my Java app (and breakpoints work correctly in my IDE - IntelliJ) using the startup:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -cp my.jar com.my.Start
```

But all the `System.out.println` statements only print server-side. I want my IDE's console to grab that output as well. How do i make this work?

Comment: You don't. If it's a server program, then it should be logging to a file, not writing to `System.out`, and you should be able to `tail` the log file.

Comment: @Andreas But can the `tail` be shown in IntelliJ?

Comment: Probably, but why would you? Just run tail in a command prompt and look at it next to the IDE.

Comment: @Andreas On a laptop, and the screen is small. So it's better in the IDE.

Comment: What do you need `System.out.println` statements for? Debugging?